# Android: Putting a border around multiple views

Tags: android, border, viewgroup, multiple-views

I am trying to figure out how to put a border around multiple views for an android app I'm working on. It seems like it should be very simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I have the following XML file saved in my drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

I then have multiple TextViews and one plain View as part of my main Android app:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/backTop"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="@string/providerHeader"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSigStrHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:text="@string/sigStrHeader"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:background="#cccccc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProvHeader"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvProv1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProv1"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProv3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvProv2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProv2"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProv4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvProv3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="" />
```

I would like to place the border (from the drawable) around all but the first TextView. I have looked at using ViewGroup but I can't seem to figure out how to make that work. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `LinearLayout` within your root layout. Then in that layout, put all the `TextViews`. Then set the linear layout background to your drawable.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:background="@drawable/backTop"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/title"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/llLinearLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/your_borderShape>

      ///All of the other text views here

  <LinearLayout/>
```

You do not have to use `LinearLayout` by the way. `RelativeLayout` is another popular option.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both and I keep getting these warnings: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2sb25hz.jpg
Can they safely be ignored, or am I missing a step?

Comment: LinearLayout doesn't allow for align start, or anything that requires another view to tell its position. That is what you would use relativeLayout for. Linear layout will just add all the view one-after-the other

Comment: Perfect! When I first tried this I was getting errors saying something about not being a sibling to the same layout, but that was just a reference issue. I removed references to the outer view and all worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not a problem! Cheers

Comment: Works for Relative layouts, too. But I used wrap content to place the border just around a limited set of buttons